# Understanding how .Internal C functions are handled in R

Tags: c, r, syntax, internals

I wonder if anyone can illustrate to me how R executes a `C` call from an R command typed at the console prompt. I am particularly confused by `R`'s treatment of a) function arguments and b) the function call itself.

Let's take an example, in this case `set.seed()`. Wondering how it works I type the name in at the prompt, get the source ([**look here for more on that**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19226816/1478381)), see there is eventually a `.Internal(set.seed(seed, i.knd, normal.kind)`, so dutifully look up the relevant function name in the `.Internals` section of `/src/names.c`, find it is called `do_setseed` and is in `RNG.c` which leads me to...

```
SEXP attribute_hidden do_setseed (SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP env)
{
    SEXP skind, nkind;
    int seed;

    checkArity(op, args);
    if(!isNull(CAR(args))) {
    seed = asInteger(CAR(args));
    if (seed == NA_INTEGER)
        error(_("supplied seed is not a valid integer"));
    } else seed = TimeToSeed();
    skind = CADR(args);
    nkind = CADDR(args);
    //...
      //DO RNG here 
    //...
    return R_NilValue;
}
```

- What are `CAR`, `CADR`, `CADDR`? My research leads me to believe they are a `Lisp` influenced construct concerning lists but beyond that I do not understand what these functions do or *why they are needed*.
- What does `checkArity()` do?
- `SEXP args` seems self explanatory, but is this a list of the
  arguments that is passed in the function call?
- What does `SEXP op` represent? I take this to mean operator (like in binary functions such as `+`), but then what is the `SEXP call` for?

Is anyone able to flow through what happens when I type

```
set.seed(1)
```

at the R console prompt, up to the point at which `skind` and `nkind` are defined? I find I am not able to well understand the source code at this level and path from interpreter to C function.

Comment: You might want to start at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html - I'll write up some more details for this particular example shortly.

Comment: @hadley thanks, I'll go through this this evening. I am really waiting for your book to be released! Soon I hope. :-)

Comment: @SimonO101: I'd add "... in R" in your question title

Comment: @OlivierDulac -- Done, thanks. For questions tagged only with the `r` tag, we normally frown on that, but since this also appears under the `c` tag, I think it's warranted.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`CAR` and `CDR` are how you access pairlist objects, as explained in [section 2.1.11 of *R Language Definition*](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Pairlist-objects).  `CAR` contains the first element, and `CDR` contains the remaining elements.  An example is given in [section 5.10.2 of *Writing R Extensions*](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Calling-_002eExternal):

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

SEXP convolveE(SEXP args)
{
    int i, j, na, nb, nab;
    double *xa, *xb, *xab;
    SEXP a, b, ab;

    a = PROTECT(coerceVector(CADR(args), REALSXP));
    b = PROTECT(coerceVector(CADDR(args), REALSXP));
    ...
}
/* The macros: */
first = CADR(args);
second = CADDR(args);
third = CADDDR(args);
fourth = CAD4R(args);
/* provide convenient ways to access the first four arguments.
 * More generally we can use the CDR and CAR macros as in: */
args = CDR(args); a = CAR(args);
args = CDR(args); b = CAR(args);
```

There's also a `TAG` macro to access the names given to the actual arguments.

`checkArity` ensures that the number of arguments passed to the function is correct. `args` are the actual arguments passed to the function. `op` is offset pointer "used for C functions that deal with more than one R function" (quoted from `src/main/names.c`, which also contains the table showing the offset and arity for each function).

For example, `do_colsum` handles `col/rowSums` and `col/rowMeans`.

```
/* Table of  .Internal(.) and .Primitive(.)  R functions
 * =====     =========        ==========
 * Each entry is a line with
 *
 *  printname  c-entry     offset  eval  arity   pp-kind   precedence  rightassoc
 *  ---------  -------     ------  ----  -----   -------   ----------  ----------
{"colSums",    do_colsum,  0,      11,   4,     {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,  0}},
{"colMeans",   do_colsum,  1,      11,   4,     {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,  0}},
{"rowSums",    do_colsum,  2,      11,   4,     {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,  0}},
{"rowMeans",   do_colsum,  3,      11,   4,     {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,  0}},
```

Note that `arity` in the above table is 4 because (even though `rowSums` et al only have 3 arguments) `do_colsum` has 4, which you can see from the `.Internal` call in `rowSums`:

```
> rowSums
function (x, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1L) 
{
    if (is.data.frame(x)) 
        x <- as.matrix(x)
    if (!is.array(x) || length(dn <- dim(x)) < 2L) 
        stop("'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions")
    if (dims < 1L || dims > length(dn) - 1L) 
        stop("invalid 'dims'")
    p <- prod(dn[-(1L:dims)])
    dn <- dn[1L:dims]
    z <- if (is.complex(x)) 
        .Internal(rowSums(Re(x), prod(dn), p, na.rm)) + (0+1i) * 
            .Internal(rowSums(Im(x), prod(dn), p, na.rm))
    else .Internal(rowSums(x, prod(dn), p, na.rm))
    if (length(dn) > 1L) {
        dim(z) <- dn
        dimnames(z) <- dimnames(x)[1L:dims]
    }
    else names(z) <- dimnames(x)[[1L]]
    z
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! This is great. So `checkArity` effectively counts the number of arguments in the function call, looks up the function and counts how many arguments that function is expecting and if they don't match it throws a controlled error to exit the function gracefully instead of calling the function with the wrong number of arguments and possibly seg-faulting?

Comment: @SimonO101: yes, it looks up the function from the table in `names.c` to see how many args are required or allowed. You can see the error by calling something like: `x <- 1; .Internal(rowSums(x))`.

Answer (score 20):

The basic C-level pairlist extraction functions are `CAR` and `CDR`. (Pairlists are very similar to lists but are implemented as a linked-list and are used internally for argument lists). They have simple R equivalents: `x[[1]]` and `x[-1]`.  R also provides lots of combinations of the two:

- `CAAR(x) = CAR(CAR(x))` which is equivalent to `x[[1]][[1]]`
- `CADR(x) = CAR(CDR(x))` which is equivalent to `x[-1][[1]]`, i.e. `x[[2]]`
- `CADDR(x) = CAR(CDR(CDR(x))` is equivalent to `x[-1][-1][[1]]`, i.e. `x[[3]]`
- and so on

Accessing the nth element of a pairlist is an `O(n)` operation, unlike accessing the nth element of a list which is `O(1)`. This is why there aren't nicer functions for accessing the nth element of a pairlist.

Internal/primitive functions don't do matching by name, they only use positional matching, which is why they can use this simple system for extracting the arguments.

Next you need to understand what the arguments to the C function are.  I'm not sure where these are documented, so I might not be completely right about the structure, but I should be the general pieces:

- `call`: the complete call, as might be captured by `match.call()`
- `op`: the index of the .Internal function called from R. This is needed because there is a many-to-1 mapping from .Internal functions to C functions. (e.g. `do_summary` implements sum, mean, min, max and prod).  The number is the third entry in `names.c` - it's always 0 for `do_setseed` and hence never used
- `args`: a pair list of the arguments supplied to the function.
- `env`: the environment from which the function was called.

`checkArity` is a macro which calls `Rf_checkArityCall`, which basically looks up the number of arguments (the fifth column in `names.c` is arity) and make sure the supplied number matches. You have to follow through quite a few macros and functions in C to see what's going on - it's very helpful to have a local copy of R-source that you can grep through.

Comment: +1 Thanks! So does the use of say `CADDR(x)` effectively keep the access time to `O(1)` (I would have thought that the time penalty for an operation like this would be minimal, as I can't think of a function where the argument list would get *that* long? It makes *much* more sense to me now, reading back my example above (combined with your book chapter which I am currently reading).

Comment: @SimonO101 No, `CADDR(x)` is going to be slower than `CDR(x)`, but you can use `CAR` and `CDR` together like in Joshua's example to avoid the overhead.